# Nuxt 3 много дочерних страниц в родительскую страницу

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue3, nuxtjs

```
pages/
├── [formid]
│   ├── index.vue
│   └── out[id].vue
├── [formid].vue
└── index.vue
```

При роуте /[formid]/* страничка рендерятся внутри [formid].vue, та что по текущему роуту

Хочу вывести как-то так

```
<NuxtLayout>
  <NuxtPage route="." />

  <div v-for="o in 25" id="'#out'+o" style="page-break-before:always">
     <NuxtPage :route="'./out'+o" />
  </div>
</NuxtLayout>
```

Но просто так route оно не принимает.

Знаю как сделать это через компоненты, но интересно можно ли это вывести дочерними страницами.

Comment: Зачем? Чего вы добиваетесь?)

Comment: Знаешь сайты есть на которых роут меняется при прокрутке вниз? Прокручивать вниз - там сначала один раздел, потом второй и тд.